# TortoiseSVN will not connect to subversion on Windows Vista 64

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, vista64

The server is running Subversion version 1.5.2 (r32768).

For the past year that I have had Tortoise installed on my works Vista 64bit laptop it NEVER connected to the remote repository. However using IntelliJ IDE I can connect to the repository just fine.

At home I am running / was running up until an hour ago TortoiseSVN 1.6.10. This was working just fine for the past few months but then after some software updates to my system and rebooting something change and now Tortoise will not connect to the remote repository either. I updated Tortoise to 1.6.12 and still it wont work.

I'm beyond frustrated with this and could use some assistance. Nobody where I work knows how to exactly setup the connections. It's either it works or not and unfortunately for me it's not.

I went into the registry and deleted all the URL entries under the tortoise setting (yeah maybe I should not have but, damn i'm just fed up at this point.) After all I have been dealing with this on and off for a year searching for answers and trying different things I run across.

So question is simply this WHAT do I need to set and where do I need to set it to get my connections working on my systems. I'm sick of having to use my IDE to do things especially when I have several projects that I need to work with updating and pushing data to.

Thank you all for whatever aid you can provide.

Here are also some log statements from bashing on tortoise to get it working.

> 1/24/2011 - 8:06:15 PM Command : Update Error : OPTIONS of 'ip/folder';: Could not resolve hostname Error : `ip/folder/proj1';: The requested name is valid, but no Error : data of the requested type was found. Error : (ip) Finished! :
>
> 1/24/2011 - 8:09:18 PM Command : Update Error : OPTIONS of 'ip/folder';: could not connect to server (ip) Finished! :

This was trying to pull a new copy of a project

> 1/24/2011 - 10:59:42 PM Command : Checkout from ip/folder, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included Error : OPTIONS of 'ip/folder';: could not connect to server (ip) Finished! :

Yes I can view the repository in Internet Explorer. Yes I can pull and push data to the repository with my IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Here are also some log statements from bashing on tortoise to get it working.

Comment: Elijah, you should be adding all of these comments as edits to your original post - see the "Edit" link at the bottom of your post.

Comment: @Elijah what's the URL you're feeding to Tortoise?

Comment: The url belongs to my company. It is not behind a firewall. I can access it directly via IE browser. I can access it via my IntelliJ IDE software. The problem is that I can not access it via TortoiseSVN. I can not give out the IP.

Comment: I meant are you using proper protocol? like `svn://192.168.3.33/repo/dir` or `file:///location/of/the/repo/dir` or `http://my.repo.org/reponame/dir`? You may try Tortoise's repository browser to locate correctly.

Comment: We are using http://my.repo.org/reponame/dir. As for Tortoise's repository browser it wont let me connect using that either.
It says that 'OPTIONS of http://my.repo.org/reponame/dir could not connect to server (http://my.repo.org)'

Comment: If I'm correct, the proxy is what you would set if you are behind a firewall. If that is correct then 2 things. 
1. I have disabled my Windows Firewall and attempted to connect and still could not.
2. If I leave the Windows Firewall on, I do not know what I am to set the values to in order to get by the firewall.
3. I dont know what file or registry or whatever I am to edit with the proxy values.

Comment: @Elijah: you know that you can mark text as blockqoute? Since you found the answer, go and answer your question yourself, add some description to the quoted text and check your own answer. That way, other users can see that the question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. I posted answer at Tigris.org http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2700618 But here is the answer also.

Alright everyone, I found the dang file that was killing me.

Environment Windows Vista 64 HP also Win 7 64 TortoiseSVN 1.6.6

- I turned off the windows feature that hides all protected files and folders.
- Found a folder in root called 'C:\ProgramData\'. Inside of this folder was a folder 'Subversion' with a file called 'servers'. No file extension on the file. So the path was C:\ProgramData\Sub​version\servers
- I used notepad to look in it and saw all my projects listed under proxy- entries. I changed the file to bkup.server (so i could revert just in case).
- Then right clicked in Windows Explorer window did an update and POOF, magic, it worked.

I hope this spares someone else out there a lot of misery. Thank you all for your help in this.

Comment: Could you accept your answer as the right one, so everyone knows there is nothing left to do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to specify a proxy server to access your repository. The proxy server is a – more or less – central access point for all computers of a corporate network to access the internet or other network resources.

If you set a proxy server in IntelliJ, copy the information from there and enter it into the TortoiseSVN proxy settings as described [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html).

To see the proxy settings for IE, open the **Internet Options**, then go to the **Connections** tab and click on **LAN Settings**. There shall be some information in the *Proxy Server* field that you can copy and enter it in Tortoise's proxy settings.

If there's no explicit proxy specified in the LAN Settings but an automatic configuration script, download the script (e.g. using `wget` or some other client that doesn't evaluate the script) and search a proxy in the downloaded script.

If neither a proxy configuration script nor an explicit proxy is given in IE, it's no proxy-related issue.

Another difference between accessing the repo with IE and accessing it with TortoiseSVN is that the IE always uses the HTTP(S) protocol to access the repo whereas Tortoise can also deal with the `svn://` protocol. Are you absolutely sure that you specified `http://server.company.com/path/to/repo` when checking out with Tortoise and not `svn://server.company.com/path/to/repo` (and is the URL that you're going to check out really the same as in IntelliJ? Which protocol is set in IntelliJ?)? The `svn://` protocol could be blocked by corporate firewalls while `http://` and `https://` will surely not be blocked by the firewall.

Comment: I have found the problem. I posted answer at Tigris.org http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2700618
But here is the answer also.

Comment: I never had the proxy set in the past. Not even too sure what a proxy is and would not know what to set them to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but my solution was inspired on yours. My subversion folder was in C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Subversion, but the 'servers' file looked normal.

In the same parent directory, I also noticed the 'TortoiseSVN' directory. So at C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\TortoiseSVN . I changed the name of that folder to xTortoiseSVN to make it unreachable for TortoiseSVN and POOF that fixed the problem. There probably was a corruption in one of the files.

Thanks for the inspiration :)